# I just been scammed of my life savings

Tags: trust

I was speaking with somebody I thought I could trust and got an https://lmemecoin.xyz link to availa of free tokens. The link requied access to my coinbase wallet. I gave it access and then the eth from my CB wallet dissapeared. I am so phyically sick. It's my life savings. I am not joking. Now the scammer has asked me for a screenshot of teh wallet transaction. As amemento? Can somebody please help. I don;t know this technology well and I am shitting myself.